# Joining Sentimentr Table with Twitter Api produced table

Tags: r, twitter, left-join

I am using Trinker's sentimentr dictionary to conduct sentiment analysis on tweets based on keyword, I was wondering, how can I join my tweets table with all the twitter information entitled Twitter_list with my sentiment scores table entitled Sentiment_Scores?

```
library(Sentimentr)

library(twitteR)


# SEARCH QUERY 
tweets <- searchTwitter("Starbucks", n=1000,lang = "en")



#convert to dataframe
   Twitter_list <- twListToDF(tweets)

Output: 
   text                     favorited   favoritedCount   Created
1  Starbucks                     TRUE            2           2019-01-12 
2  starbucks is the              FALSE           2           2019-01-11 
3  starbucks sucks               FALSE           1           2019-01-10 
4  Iced starbucks rules          FALSE           1           2019-01-09 
5  I love starbucks so much      True            3           2019-01-08 



# Sentiment Score of Text 
Sentiment_Scores <- sentiment(Twitter_list$text)

Output:
       element_id   Sentance_id   Word_Count  Sentiment 
1           1            1            2        0.1856953
2           2            1            5        0.1856953
3           3            1            2        0.1856953
4           4            1            1        0.1856953
5           5            1            3        0.1856953
```

Ideally I would like the output to look like

```
 text                  favorited  favoritedCount   Created  Word_Count Sentiment
1  Starbucks                TRUE           2     2019-01-12   1        0.1856953
2  starbucks is the         FALSE          2     2019-01-11   3        0.1856953
3  starbucks sucks          FALSE          1     2019-01-10   2        0.1856953
4  Iced starbucks rules     FALSE          1     2019-01-09   3        0.1856953
5  I love starbucks so much True           3     2019-01-08   5        0.1856953
```

Comment: How does I love starbucks go from a word count of 3 to 5? There must be  a way to have a common column in both datasets. Otherwise, I don't see how 3 becomes 5 unless you do the wordcount yourself. Take a look at row 5 in both data sets.

Answer (score 0):

This? Tweets is your `tweets` `data.frame` while `sents` is `sentiment_scores`.

```
library(tidyverse)
new_tweets<-tweets %>% 
  mutate(ID=as.factor(row_number()))
new_sents<-sents %>% 
  mutate(ID=as.factor(row_number()))
merged<-new_tweets %>% 
        left_join(new_sents,by="ID") %>% 
        select(-ID)
merged
```

You can merge them with `cbind` first and examine.

```
new_tweets<-new_tweets[,-ncol(new_tweets)]
combined<-cbind(new_tweets,new_sents)
as.tibble(combined)
 MyText     favorited favoritedCount Created element_id Sentance_id Word_Count Sentiment ID   
  <fct>      <lgl>              <int> <fct>        <int>       <int>      <int>     <dbl> <fct>
1 Starbucks  TRUE                   2 2019-0~          1           1          2     0.186 1    
2 starbucks~ FALSE                  2 2019-0~          2           1          5     0.186 2    
3 starbucks~ FALSE                  1 2019-0~          3           1          2     0.186 3    
4 Icedstarb~ FALSE                  1 2019-0~          4           1          1     0.186 4    
5 Ilovestar~ TRUE                   3 2019-0~          5           1          3     0.186 5
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, this is very close to what I am looking for. However, the provided code does not correctly join the tables. When looking at word count the numbers do not match the count of the text, therefore, assigning the wrong sentiment score. If you have any other recommendations on how to match the tables, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm away from my computer and handled this question hours ago. Check my edit and see if it helps.I can't really tell because I have no access to your entire data and/or current output so I don't know what's not working. With your provided data it worked.